# Did the rep requirement for the "view vote counts" privilege change?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

I had the ability to view the vote count of answers awhile ago when my rep was lower, but the privilege suddenly stopped working. So I looked at the [site's privileges page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), and it now says you need 750 rep to view vote count.

What happened? was it a bug that I could see them to begin with, or did someone decide you need a higher rep than originally decided?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reputation required for the various privileges changes depending on whether a site is in private beta, public beta or it has launched as a full site.

A (somewhat outdated) comparison of the reputation requirements [can be found here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared). The current reputation requirements are always available [by clicking on your reputation score on your profile page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/privileges).